# Dihedral groups acting on Riemann surfaces

Tags: group-actions, riemann-surfaces, dihedral-groups

I'm studying the quotient riemann surface $X/G$. I'm looking for examples of dihedral groups $D_n$ acting on some riemann surfaces $X$ or at least acting on it's Jacobian JX. Does anybody knows some examples of this type? Maybe some paper, book, etc. I don't if there is something about this.

Thanks

Comment: Carval, could you formulate it more clear -- what and why are you interested in?